# Muon-catalyzed fusion: muon number

Tags: plasma-physics, fusion

I recently read a paper "Meson-catalyzed fusion in ultradense plasmas" (it is behind a paywall: only subscribers to Physical Reviews E can read it) that claims that muon-catalyzed fusion in substances such as warm-dense matter lead to cycling rates many orders of magnitude greater than the rates shown for other scenarios. They also claim gains in the range of ~10-10000. I should note that the gains here are the ratios of the energy output to the energy required to produce the muons and that they make these claims using the traditional method of muon production and the method of electro-disintegration of deuterium and tritium to produce pions. However even if these gains are correct (and I am skeptical), there is another issue that I don't see anyone mention when discussing the potential of using muon-catalyzed fusion (MCF) as a power source: muon number. If we wanted to use MCF in a practical power plant, I am quite sure that the number of muons we would need is unobtainable at the moment. Is there something I am missing that negates the problem?

Despite this, it may be possible to use MCF to spark traditional inertial confinement fusion (ICF), but the only advantage that this has that I know of is that it would be impacted less by instabilities compared to normal fast-ignition ICF.

Comment: https://journals.aps.org/prab/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevAccelBeams.20.030101 reports approx. 1e6 muons per Watt of proton beam power. I don't know how efficient a proton accelerator in the 400MeV range is, but it could probably be made reasonably efficient (in the tens of %) for a technological application.

Comment: Based on the formula for the energy output in the paper I cited and if one wanted 300 MW from the power plant one would need around 10^21 muons present in the plasma. Again, I might be missing something, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: I didn't run the numbers. I think the most optimistic calculations I have ever seen were citing 10% efficiency for muon catalyzed fusion. Roughly an order of magnitude short of breakeven. Maybe a bit better than that, but never enough.

Comment: Ten percent of what?

Comment: 10% of the theoretical energy needed to produce the muons. Less comes out that we have to put in.

Comment: The paper above claimed that with warm dense matter, the lowest gain (energy out/ energy needed to make the muons) would be 33.1. However even if this is correct, the realistic energy output would not even be one Joule.

Comment: https://indico.gsi.de/event/9971/attachments/30541/37961/HEDP_cover_2k18_gsi_c.pdf